# JavaScript Check if array using categories contains string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array containing the following data.

```
[ { name: 'hello', value: 'Bot hello!' },
  { name: 'help', value: 'Print help sheet.' },
  { name: 'kick', value: 'Kicks a user.' },
  { name: 'ping', value: 'Check the bot\'s Connection' },
  { name: 'roll', value: 'Roll a die.' } ]

var str = "ping"
if (str == //One of the names in the array){
   //Do stuff

}
```

How can I create a function to check whether a string such as "ping" is equal to one of the values in the "name:" category? I want this to be dynamic so if the string is equal to "roll" it will flag that roll is in the array.

Comment: You can use `Array#some` like this: `if(arr.some(o => o.name === str)) { ... }`.

Comment: Please try searching before asking

Comment: Sorry. I tried searching however I couldn't find anything for using sub arrays. Anyway the example provided in the one you linked works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6:

```js
var data = [ { name: 'hello', value: 'Bot hello!' },
  { name: 'help', value: 'Print help sheet.' },
  { name: 'kick', value: 'Kicks a user.' },
  { name: 'ping', value: 'Check the bot\'s Connection' },
  { name: 'roll', value: 'Roll a die.' } ]
  
var str = "ping"

console.log(data.some(x => x.name === str))
```

Comment: Yes this works :) Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

You could use native array method [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/some)

```
function contain(array, value) {
  return array.some(a => a.name === value);
}
if (contain(array, 'ping')){
   //Do stuff

}
```

Comment: Why use `find` and not use its return value (properly). Use `some` for checking, and `find` for actual finding.

Comment: This was returning an error saying that the { in the if statement wasn't valid.

Comment: @nathanial292 updated, i forgot one ")".

Comment: Do you know how to then get the matching value in the array. Where the string matches the name?

Comment: array.find(a => a.name === value);